# Unrecognised selector sent to instance while uploading image with parameters in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, multipartform-data, alamofire

I am trying to upload images with parameters using Alamofire. Images are set and they are not nil. When I try to append the body part with multipart form data, I get unrecognised selector as seen below. What am I doing wrong here? Using Swift 2.2. Any help will be appreciated.

```
let parameters: [String : AnyObject] = ["f_name": keychain.get(userNameKeychain)!, "l_name": "", "email": "d.tha@aexonic.com", "password": keychain.get(passwordKeychain)!,"image": self.imgProfilePic.image!, "cover_image": self.imgBannerImage.image!, "country": keychain.get(countryKeychain)!, "street_address_1": keychain.get(streetAddress1Keychain)!, "street_address_2": keychain.get(streetAddress2Keychain)!, "brand_name": self.strBrandName, "town_city": keychain.get(cityKeychain)!, "state": keychain.get(stateKeychain)!, "zip": keychain.get(zipKeychain)!, "dob": timeStamp!, "latitude": self.latitude!, "longitude": self.longitude!, "is_verify": keychain.getBool(phoneNumberVerifyKeychain)!, "phone": keychain.get(phoneNumberKeychain)!];

        print(url_register);
        print("Parameters to post: \(parameters)");


         //"cover_image": ""
         //"image": ""
         // ABOVE TWO PARAMETERS NEED TO BE THERE IN parameters TO UPLOAD 2 IMAGES
         Alamofire.upload(.POST, url_register, headers: [authorization: authHeader], multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                // import image to request
                if self.imgProfilePic.image != nil {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgProfilePic.image!, 1) {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "image", fileName: "profile.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                    }

                    // import parameters
                    for (key, value) in parameters {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key) //*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x380bf6cc'
                    }
                }

                if self.imgBannerImage.image != nil {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgBannerImage.image!, 1) {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "cover_image", fileName: "cover.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                    }

                    // import parameters
                    for (key, value) in parameters {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
                    }
                }

            }, // you can customise Threshold if you wish. This is the alamofire's default value
            encodingMemoryThreshold: Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                case .Failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
                stopHUD(self.view);
        })
```

Comment: apparently one of the `value` it gets from `parameters` isn't something that can receive the message `dataUsingEncoding()`. That only works on Strings. You probably want to print each `value` in your `for` loop to debug which `value` is causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah you were correct.. I changed parameters from [String: AnyObject] to [String: String] and it worked!. Thanks @dirkgroten Post this as an answer so that I can accept and up vote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently one of the `value` it gets from `parameters` isn't something that can receive the message `dataUsingEncoding()`. That only works on Strings. You probably want to print each `value` in your `for` loop to debug which `value` is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer guide us helped us clear the error.